# Python loop to read the shell output line by line and print on html page via flask

Tags: python, html, linux, shell, flask

[Browser Output as per the below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkSKI.jpg)

Im trying to print the output of ping command out to the browser on html via FLASK . The command works perfectly, but however it seems to be reading just the first line and printing it out to my "home.html" file

I did try my hand with check_output as file, while it succeeds in printing the output ,it doesnt seem to be streaming the ping output to html page in realtime. It does so after the output is consolidated.

Here;s the code

```
@app.route ("/test",methods=['POST','GET'])  
def ping():
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            ['ping -c 10 8.8.8.8'], ## Any Linux Shell command              
            shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in iter(proc.stdout.read,''):
            print(line)
            return render_template('home.html', out=line.decode(),mimetype='text/html')  

        

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=5000)
```

I'm aiming to show the output of this command ("ping" or any linux shell command) on HTML  in a live output stream i.e printing it as soon as the shell output is shown in the terminal.

This image shows the output as seen on my browser

Comment: Any luck building this? Would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: Unfortunately No, i tried a few techniques but couldnt get it to stream the output to the page .